# how use ng-if in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table with results:

```
<tr ng-repeat="result in results">
    <td>{{result.foo}}</td>
    <td ng-if="result.bar == '1'">it's One!</td>
    <td ng-if="result.bar != '1'">it's not One! is {{result.bar}}</td>
</tr>
```

the 3 are displayed, why the ng-if is not working?

the results are correctly setted in the scope because the "it's not One! is 5 is displayed OK"

Comment: could you show controller code or results data structure

Comment: <td ng-if="5 == 6">foo</td> it's displayed, why?

Comment: i've solved my problem, its the angular version, with 1.2.12 ng-if works, but with the 1.0.1 not. test with this example:
    Click me: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-init="checked=true" /><br/>
    Show when checked:
    <span ng-if="checked" class="animate-if">
      I'm removed when the checkbox is unchecked.
    </span>

Comment: ye i was just going to point you out on that

Answer (score 1):

it's a version problem.

html example:

```
Click me: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-init="checked=true" /><br/>
Show when checked:
<span ng-if="checked" class="animate-if">
  I'm removed when the checkbox is unchecked.
</span>
```

works with:

```
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.12/angular.min.js"></script>
```

but not with:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it doesn't work, but you could try an alternative way of doing it:

```
<tr ng-repeat="result in results">
  <td>{{result.foo}}</td>
  <ng-switch on="result.bar">
       <td ng-switch-when="1">it's One!</td>
       <td ng-switch-when="2">it's not One! is {{result.bar}}</td>
  </ng-switch>
</tr>
```